# filter out the objects from JSON array based on conditions using Mule4 dataweave

Tags: filter, mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have a Json array which has the transactions. Basically, here I'm trying to filter out the records that has equal payments (Payment received  should have date greater than payment returned/reversed).

Sample Input :

```
 [
  { 
    "CreatedDate": "2023-11-05T23:56:34.000Z",
    "payment": "76.25",    
    "invNum": {
      "Name": "OB-0153834"
    },
    "type": "Payment - Received"
  },
  {    
    "CreatedDate": "2023-11-05T00:05:18.000Z",
    "payment": "-76.25",
    "invNum": {     
      "Name": "OB-0153834"
    },
    "type": "Payment - Refunded"
  },
  {
    "CreatedDate": "2023-11-06T00:47:30.000Z",
    "payment": "-45.0",
    "invNum": {
      "Name": "OB-0153837"
    },
    "type": "Payment - Reversed"
  },
  {
    "CreatedDate": "2023-11-06T00:26:07.000Z",
    "payment": "110.0",
    "invNum": {
      "Name": "OB-0153837"
    },
    "type": "Payment - Received"
  },
  {
    "CreatedDate": "2023-11-06T00:43:46.000Z",
    "payment": "45.0",
    "invNum": {
      "Name": "OB-0153837"
    },
    "type": "Payment - Received"
  },
  {
    "CreatedDate": "2023-11-02T18:59:18.000Z",
    "payment": "50.0",
    "invNum": {
      "Name": "OB-0153817"
    },
    "type": "Payment - Received"
  }
]
```

Expected :

```
[
  {
    "CreatedDate": "2023-11-02T18:59:18.000Z",
    "payment": "50.0",
    "invNum": {
      "Name": "OB-0153817"
    },
    "type": "Payment - Received"
  },
      {
      "CreatedDate": "2023-11-06T00:26:07.000Z",
      "payment": "110.0",
      "invNum": {
        "Name": "OB-0153837"
      },
      "type": "Payment - Received"
    }
]
```

Filter out Conditions :

1. With same Name
2. filter out set of records which has same amount but with '-' sign(i.e equal amounts 76 and -76 should be filtered out) and created on same date.
3. Record with - value should have date after the + value .

Comment: Can you please elaborate about your expected response? Why you have that one object only? Its little confusing. Also can you please add what you tried @Satish Reddy

Comment: Basically we are trying to nullify the  payment transactions based on the equal amount with negative sign. 
For ex. 
In above sample input,  first record  transaction with amount 76.25 happened at 11 pm and later one more transaction for the same name  with same negative amount transaction is happened which we need to nullify them in backend . 
Out of 3 transactions, 2 got the payments reversed/refunded. Im expecting the remaining transaction in the output that yet to refund/reverse transaction.

Comment: @Karthik sorry my updated, I m expecting two records in output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 things you mentioned

1. Name match
2. Positive and Negative Sign match
3. If the point 2 matches then its - CreatedDate should be greater than + CreatedDate

By your example, the below condition fails since Created Date 2023-11-05T00:05:18.000Z is not greater than 2023-11-05T23:56:34.000Z

```
[
  {
    "CreatedDate": "2023-11-05T00:05:18.000Z",
    "payment": "-76.25",
    "invNum": {
      "Name": "OB-0153834"
    },
    "type": "Payment - Refunded"
  },
  {
    "CreatedDate": "2023-11-05T23:56:34.000Z",
    "payment": "76.25",
    "invNum": {
      "Name": "OB-0153834"
    },
    "type": "Payment - Received"
  }
  ]
```

DW

I grouped By `paymentNumber ++ - ++ Name` since we want to eliminate matching payment number of a matching Name

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
flatten(
    (payload orderBy($.payment as Number) 
        groupBy (($.payment replace "-" with "")++"-"++($.invNum.Name)) pluck $)
            filter(item,index)->
                !(((("-" ++ item.payment[1]) default "") == ((item.payment[0]) default "")) 
                    and (((item.CreatedDate[1]) default "") < ((item.CreatedDate[0]) default ""))
                    and (((item."type"[1]) default "") == "Payment - Received" and ((item."type"[0]) default "") != "Payment - Received")))
```

**Edit**
I applied multiple groups

1. To group name and payment
2. To group type over name and payment

DW

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
flatten(((
    (payload
        groupBy (($.payment replace "-" with "")++"-"++($.invNum.Name)))pluck $) 
        map ($ orderBy(-$.payment) 
        groupBy (($.payment replace "-" with "")++"-"++($.invNum.Name)++"-"++(
            if(($."type")=="Payment - Reversed" or (($."type")=="Payment - Refunded"))
                    "Payment - Rev"
            else "Payment - Received"
        ))))
        map($ pluck $)
        map(item,index)->(
            if((sizeOf(item[0]) default 0) >= (sizeOf(item[1]) default 0))
                do{
                    var item0= (item[0] filter !(
                ((abs($.payment) default "") == (abs(item[1].payment[$$]) default ""))and
                ((($.CreatedDate) default "") < ((item[1].CreatedDate[$$]) default "")) 
                ))
                ---
                if(sizeOf(item[0])==sizeOf(item0))
                (item[0] default []) ++ (item[1] default [])
                else item0
                }               
            else
               do {
                    var item1=(item[1] filter !(
                ((abs($.payment) default "") == (abs(item[0].payment[$$]) default ""))and
                ((($.CreatedDate) default "") > ((item[0].CreatedDate[$$]) default ""))   
                ))
                ---
                if(sizeOf(item[1])==sizeOf(item1))
                (item[0] default []) ++ (item[1] default [])
                else item1
                }
                
            )
)
```

Comment: Thanks @karthik for your help. It's working for all the scenarios except one.

* In case of customer receives the same amount twice in a day and reversed only once,
We have to output the one of the record with + value and and happens later point of time .

Comment: [{ "CreatedDate": "2023-11-05T03:56:34.000Z",
    "payment": "76.25"}, {"CreatedDate": "2023-11-05T04:56:34.000Z",
    "payment": "76.25"}, {"CreatedDate": "2023-11-06T23:56:34.000Z",
    "payment": "-76.25"} ]
expected output : [{"CreatedDate": "2023-11-05T05:56:34.000Z",
    "payment": "76.25"}]
Note : Adding the part of the payload for understanding. Actual payload structure is same as in question.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @SatishReddy I modified answer

Comment: Thanks @karthik, still output is [] response if I try with same payment numbers (- or + ) . 
 [{ "CreatedDate": "2023-11-05T13:56:34.000Z","payment": "76.25","invNum": { "Name": "OB-0153834" }, "type": "Payment - Received" },  { "CreatedDate": "2023-11-05T14:14:18.000Z","payment": "-76.25", "invNum": { "Name": "OB-0153834" }, "type": "Payment - Refunded"}, {"CreatedDate": "2023-11-05T15:05:18.000Z","payment":"76.25",  // or "-76.25" "invNum": { "Name": "OB-0153834"},"type": "Payment - Refunded" }] 
For above input, I'm expecting the third record as output irrespective of sign of the value.

Comment: @SatishReddy Please try again , I have edited it. Appologies for making it too complex

Comment: Thanks @karthik , in below scenario its failing to output 2 records. 
[{ 
    "CreatedDate": "2023-11-05T22:56:34.000Z",
    "CloudCollect__Payment_Amount__c": "76.25",    
    "CloudCollect__Invoice_Number__r": {
      "Name": "OB-0153834"
    },
    "CloudCollect__Payment_Type__c": "Payment - Received"
  },
  {    
    "CreatedDate": "2023-11-05T21:05:18.000Z",
    "CloudCollect__Payment_Amount__c": "-76.25",
    "CloudCollect__Invoice_Number__r": {     
      "Name": "OB-0153834"
    },
    "CloudCollect__Payment_Type__c": "Payment - Refunded"
  }]

Comment: @SatishReddy modified answer. Please do verify it again

Comment: It's working as expected. Thank you so much @karthik for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Try following script

```
%dw 2.0
var data=(payload.payment map(abs($)) orderBy $)
var fil=data map(
    if($ == data[$$+1]) $ else null
)
output application/json
---
payload filter (!(fil contains abs($.payment as Number)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script uses nested grouping, first by name and then by date. Once all the payments for a name and date is obtained, it separates the received & reversed payments. If there are any reversed payments, the script filters out the matching payment from the received payment recursively.

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
output application/json

var refundPaymentStrings = ["Payment - Refunded", "Payment - Reversed"]

var byName = payload groupBy $.invNum.Name

var getDate = (dateValue) -> dateValue as Date

//Combine received payments after removing the matched payment
fun combineRecvdPayments (payments) = 
  payments.l ++ (if (sizeOf (payments.r) > 1) payments.r[1 to -1] else [])

//Recursively remove the matching payments
fun matchAndRemovePayments (revPayments, revIdx: Number, recdPayments) = 
    if (revIdx < (sizeOf (revPayments)))
        matchAndRemovePayments (revPayments, 
                revIdx + 1, 
                combineRecvdPayments(recdPayments splitWhere 
                                        abs($.payment) == abs(revPayments[revIdx].payment)
                                    )
            )
    else recdPayments

//Group the payments on date next. separate reversed and recvd payments
//Once separated, remove the matching payments from recvd payments
fun filterReversedPayments (payments) = 
    valuesOf (payments groupBy (getDate($.CreatedDate))) 
        map (value) -> do {
                var revPayments = value filter (refundPaymentStrings contains $."type")
                var recdPayments = value filter $."type" == "Payment - Received"
                ---
                if ((! isEmpty(revPayments)))
                    matchAndRemovePayments(revPayments, 0, recdPayments)
                else recdPayments
        }
---
//Grouping by Name first and Iterating through the payments per Name
(valuesOf (byName) flatMap (payment) -> flatten (filterReversedPayments(payment))) orderBy $.CreatedDate
```